# Eclipse plugin to format Python comments

Tags: windows, python, eclipse, programming

I am looking for an Eclipse plugin that can format Python comments as shown below:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

If possible, it should work for Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: I haven't found any solutions so far.

Comment: I'm still interested.